# Responsive jQuery navigation show dropdown menu on click for mobile and on hover for desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, responsive

I'm developing a responsive/mobile navigation header using jQuery for submenu animations. On a small screen, I want the user to click the parent `<li>` to animate the dropdown and on a large screen I want them to hover over the parent `<li>`.

The content of `#navigation-links` is appended to the `.mobile-nav ul` on window resize using jQuery.

HTML:

```
<ul id="navigation-links">
    <li>Item without Submenu</li>
    <li>Item without Submenu</li>
    <li>Item with Submenu
        <ul>
            <li>Submenu Item</li>
            <li>Submenu Item</li>
            <li>Submenu Item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item with Submenu
        <ul>
            <li>Submenu Item</li>
            <li>Submenu Item</li>
            <li>Submenu Item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item without Submenu</li>
    <li>Item without Submenu</li>
</ul>
<div class="mobile-nav">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// Screen size larger than 600px
$("#navigation-links li").hover(function () {
    $(this).children("ul").animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, 400);
});


// Screen size smaller than 600px
$('.mobile-nav li').click(function () {
    if ($(this).has('ul')) {
        $(this).children('ul').animate({height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle'}, 250);
    }
});
```

On page load, the function works correctly; however, if you resize the screen (from small to large or vice versa), the function works as if it were still the original screen size.

Ex: if you load the screen small and click a parent `<li>`, the menu drops down. Then resize the screen to large and you still have to click the parent `<li>`, as opposed to hovering.

[Link to site with issue](http://ashleybrookephoto.com/wp/)

Comment: Have you found the answer? If yes then please share it because I am also getting the same issue.